# Python code that gives user taxes owed (does not work)

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am student learning how to code in Python and one of my first assignments is to create code that will return the amount of taxes owed based on annual income. I have used specific numbers from a file for class, but there is something wrong with my code and I can't figure out what it is.

I am working in Visual Studio and have attached an image of my code [mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KRXa.png)

Comment: Please post your actual code in here

Comment: Okay, thank you. I saw an option to do that when creating my post but ran into some formatting issues. Is that how I should do it in the future? rather than posting an image of my code?

Comment: Yes, you should always put enough code in your question (as actual text, not an image) that we can reproduce the error, but not too much that we can't navigate the code. You can post extremely long outputs on an external server like pastebin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Call your function

`taxes` is a function. `print(taxes)` prints this function. `print(taxes(Income))` will calculate the taxes for the income and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first off, use pastebin or GitHub gists when uploading code. This is so we can run your code faster. You also need to be more specific about what you mean by your code is not working. My bet is that you forgot to call the function itself. Also, since your new I recommend you take a look at Pycharm. I also improved your code a bit:

```
def taxes(income):
    if income < 9076: return .1*income
    elif income < 36901: return .15*income
    elif income < 89351: return .25*income + 5081.25
    elif income < 186351: return .28*income + 18193.75
    elif income < 405101: return .33*income + 45353.75
    elif income < 406751: return .35*income + 117541.25
    return .396*income + 118118.75  # else statement is redundant when returning values
while True:
    try:
        income = float(input('Enter your annual Income: '))
        break
    except ValueError: print('Please try again')
print('The total tax owed is:', taxes(income))
# print(f'The total tax owed is: {taxes(income}}')  # python 3.6 only
# or you can use .format or %s as well
```